# Rails user creates multiple posts with one click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application the user can create posts. But a user should be able to write multiple posts on one page and they should be all created when the submitbutton is clicked. How could this be done?

Max

Comment: @Ilya That's not necessarily true, and wholly unhelpful.

Comment: This isn't super straightforward, so you're going to have to dig in a bit, but it's totally do-able. I'd recommend using a [form object](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects) and iterate over the `Post` objects to create them.

Comment: @coreyward I'm not sure how this works

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using accepts_nested_attributes_for? In your comment you said there's no parent model, but wouldn't the User model be the parent model of the post? The railscast below really helped me with this

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Comment: The problem is that this railscast isnt free

Comment: but when I use nested attributes, all the stuff is happen in the user_controller, isn't it? But that means that the whole application has to be recreated

Comment: and everytime I want to create a post a new user has to be created

Comment: You can find the railscast on youtube for free @Max. Also don't be afraid to throwaway code. We have to do it all the time :) Also, you don't have to create a new user for every post. Customize or make your own method in the controller so that it's '@user.posts.create' or current_user.posts.create